# Doctrine MongoDB - is there any way to build a query from JSON?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

I have an arbitrary MongoDB JSON find query string, for example:

```
{ "address.city": "Seattle"}
```

or

```
{ qty: { $gt: 5, $lt: 50 }
```

Is there any existing method to create a Doctrine.MongoDB.Query object from the JSON string? Or alternately to query mongo directly and then pass those results to doctrine for hydration?

Comment: It is a hack, but currently I am working around this by running an extra query. First JSON query runs against mongo directly and collects all the _ids as $idList. Then run the doctrine query as field('id')->in($idList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but this recent bundle appears to have been created to serve this exact purpose (querybuilderjs into doctrine).

https://github.com/fourlabsldn/QBJSParserBundle

https://github.com/fourlabsldn/QBJSParser

```
         $parsedRuleGroup = $this->get('fl_qbjs_parser.json_query_parser.doctrine_orm_parser')->parseJsonString($jsonString, Product::class);

         $query = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->createQuery($parsedRuleGroup->getDqlString());
         $query->setParameters($parsedRuleGroup->getParameters());
         $results = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any existing method to create a Doctrine.MongoDB.Query object from the JSON string?

At this moment no, however we could add `setQuery` method to the `Builder`. More tedious, but working, would be instantiating `Query` class on your own.

> Or alternately to query mongo directly and then pass those results to doctrine for hydration?

Once you have plain arrays with data (and you're not afraid to dive into `UnitOfWork`) you may utilize [$dm->getUnitOfWork()->getOrCreateDocument()](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/957ab471ef4b60669dc6d0e283411e33deec8c0a/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php#L2635) or employ `HydratorFactory` and merge documents into `DocumentManager` later.